# generate G-code | decompose b-spline to circular sections

Tags: geometry, cad, opencascade, cnc, g-code

I'm trying to decompose a b-spline to a set of circle definitions.
I'm trying to generate G-code; the idea here is to segment a b-spline into a number of circular interpolations [ G02 ]. Using PythonOCC I can break up the b-spline into a number of beziers curves, but I don't know how to translate the bezier into circular sections.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most scientific approach but it worth a look: http://rocksolidperspective.com/2010/02/17/making-splines-work-in-manufacturing/